# SQL - Search for table name across all databases on server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I thought this would be pretty straightforward, but I have about 80 databases in the server I am looking at, each database has 5-500 tables.

I am wondering how i can search for a TABLE NAME across everything. I tried a basic

```
SELECT 
*

FROM sys.tables
```

but I only get 6 results.

Comment: You will have to use a cursor with dynamic SQL to query `sys.tables`, with a leading `USE` statement for each database.

Comment: If you're able to install an add-on to SSMS, I would recommend SQL Search. It's free and very useful. https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think it should work:

```
sp_msforeachdb 'select ''?'' from ?.information_schema.tables where table_name=''YourTableName''';
```

It will output the names of the DBs that contain a table with the given name.

Here's a version using `print` that is a little better IMHO:

```
sp_msforeachdb '
    if exists(select * from ?.information_schema.tables where table_name=''YourTableName'')
        print ''?'' ';
```

The above queries are using [ms_foreachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/), a stored procedure that runs a given query on all databases present on the current server.

Comment: What exactly is this doing?

Comment: @baineschile I added a little explanation.

Comment: BTW, this undocumented procedure will sometimes skip databases. Aaron Bertrand has a great replacement this and an explanation here. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

Answer (score 3):

This version uses FOR XML PATH('') instead of string concatenation, eliminates the default system databases, handles databases with non-standard names and supports a search pattern.

```
DECLARE @pattern NVARCHAR(128) = '%yourpattern%';
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = STUFF((
    SELECT 'union all select DatabaseName = name from ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + '.sys.tables where name like ''' + @pattern + ''' '
    FROM sys.databases d
    WHERE d.database_id > 4
    FOR XML path('')
    ), 1, 10, '');

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You might need to write:

```
select DatabaseName = name collate Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

I know I did.

Comment: This is a better approach than what I posted. Well done!!

Answer (score 2):

Just because I really dislike loops I wanted to post an alternative to answers already posted that are using cursors.

This leverages dynamic sql and the sys.databases table.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select DatabaseName = name from [' + name + '].sys.tables where name = ''YourTableName'' union all '
from sys.databases

set @SQL = stuff(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 9, 11, '') --removes the last UNION ALL

exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: you could also use SQL Search from Redgate or ApexSQL Search from Apex.  They're free

Comment: @user1443098 well sure but the OP was trying to do this with sql. :)

Comment: @user1443098 I was demonstrating some code that isn't using those cursors. I cringe when I see a cursor, even in the rare situations where it is actually needed.

Comment: when you need to iterate through databases, there's really no better way.  There are alternatives but nothing set-based

Comment: But you don't have to iterate through them...look up. :) This of course is still a number of queries but no loop and the result is a single resultset.

Comment: as soon as you write "SELECT \@SQL = \@SQL +" you've got iteration (and FOR XML PATH('') would be better even here).  It's one of the alternatives that has no advantage.

Comment: Other than being simpler to write, requires far less typing and returns the output in a single result set instead of many yes it has no advantage. It was posted as an alternative to the cursor approach posted by many others. Not sure why you feel you have prove me wrong here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167355/discussion-between-user1443098-and-sean-lange).

Comment: +1 By far this is the best approach. There is zero need to install additional tools to do this. If you already have those tools you probably aren’t asking this question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of a simpler option using dynamic sql.  This will get you the name of all tables in every database in your environment:

```
declare @table table (idx int identity, name varchar(max))
insert @table
select name from master.sys.databases

declare @dbname varchar(max)
declare @iterator int=1
while @iterator<=(select max(idx) from @table) begin

select @dbname=name from @table where idx=@iterator

exec('use ['+@dbname+'] select name from sys.tables')

set @iterator=@iterator+1
end

select * from @table
```

Comment: This will fail if you drop a database. It will also fail if you have a database name with spaces or other funky characters.

Comment: Good point @SeanLange - Edited to use qualifying brackets for database name with spaces or other funky characters

Comment: I'm artificially creating numbers for each database in my table variable by using identity - that way whatever dbs exist at run time will be looped through

Comment: Yeah just noticed that. Seems a bit complicated but whatever, there are a million ways to skin this cat. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'', 
s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI,
t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI
FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t
ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id] WHERE t.name like 
''%YOUR_TABLE_NAME%''';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id > 4
AND [state] = 0
AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));

--PRINT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Dim sql As String = ("Select * from " & ComboboxDatabaseName.Text & ".sys.tables")

use this key

Comment: This is an answer in Visual Basic when the question was about SQL.